# How to send an SMS programmatically using java?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, sms

I need to send an SMS through my Java Application. I had piece of code that used to work perfectly well where I had made use of a SMS sending site.  However the site introduced captcha verification because of which my code fails. Please find the below code that I had tried. Request you to please guide me through any other alternatives that I can make use of sending SMS through Java.

```
package com.test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

public class Mobiletry2 
{
private final String LOGIN_URL    = "http://*****.com/login.php";
private final String SEND_SMS_URL = "http://*****.com/home.php";
private final String LOGOUT_URL = "http://*****.com/logout.php?LogOut=1";

private final int MESSAGE_LENGTH = 10;
private final int MOBILE_NUMBER_LENGTH = 140;
private final int PASSWORD_LENGTH = 10;

private String mobileNo;
private String password;
private DefaultHttpClient httpclient;
Mobiletry2(String username,String password)
{
 this.mobileNo = username;
 this.password = password;
 httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
}



public boolean isLoggedIn() throws IOException {
 // User Credentials on Login page are sent using POST
 // So create httpost object
 HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost(LOGIN_URL);

 // Add post variables to login url
 List<NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
 nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("MobileNoLogin", mobileNo));
 nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("LoginPassword", password));
 httpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps));

 // Execute request
 HttpResponse response = this.httpclient.execute(httpost);

 //Check response entity
 HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
       if (entity != null) {
           System.out.println("entity " + slurp(entity.getContent(), 10000000));
           System.out.println("entity " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

        return true;
       }
 return false;
}

public boolean sendSMS(String toMobile,String message) throws IOException {
 HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost(SEND_SMS_URL);
 List<NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
 nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("MobileNos", toMobile));
               nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Message", message));

               httpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps));
 HttpResponse response = this.httpclient.execute(httpost);
 HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
 if(entity != null) {
                       System.out.println("entity " + slurp(entity.getContent(), 10000000));
                       System.out.println("entity " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
  return true;
 }
 return false;
}

public boolean logoutSMS() throws IOException {
 HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(LOGOUT_URL);
 HttpResponse response;
 response = this.httpclient.execute(httpGet);
 HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
 if (entity != null) {
  System.out
    .println("entity " + slurp(entity.getContent(), 10000000));
  System.out.println("entity "
    + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
  return true;
 }
 return false;
}


public static String slurp(final InputStream is, final int bufferSize)
{
  final char[] buffer = new char[bufferSize];
  final StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
  try {
    final Reader in = new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8");
    try {
      for (;;) {
        int rsz = in.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
        if (rsz < 0)
          break;
        out.append(buffer, 0, rsz);
      }
    }
    finally {
      in.close();
    }
  }
  catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
    /* ... */
  }
  catch (IOException ex) {
      /* ... */
  }
  return out.toString();
}

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
 //Replace DEMO_USERNAME with username of your account
 String username = "********";
 //Replace DEMO_PASSWORD with password of your account
 String password = "****";
 //Replace TARGET_MOBILE with a valid mobile number 
 String toMobile = "****";

 String toMessage = "Hello";

 Mobiletry2 sMS = new Mobiletry2(username, password);
 try{
  if(sMS .isLoggedIn() && sMS .sendSMS(toMobile,toMessage))
  {
   sMS.logoutSMS();
   System.out.println("Message was sent successfully " );
  }
 }
 catch(IOException e)
 {
  System.out.println("Unable to send message, possible cause: " + e.getMessage());
 }
}
}
```

Comment: have you tried with [twilio](http://www.twilio.com)

Comment: Does fullonsms.com have another API meant for machines? Maybe a SOAP or REST API or even SMPP or CIMD2 API (in all cases there will be some learning involved) There are lots of providers out there, but generally they want you to show ads or else get a paid-for account.

Comment: So, you're saying you've abused a service without paying and they introduced a mean to stop that and now you want us to help you circumvent that protection?

Comment: @DarkDust The site is used to send free smses. Hence there was nothing wroing in sending smses through the site. What my query is there any other alternative like any **Java API** that i can make use of to send sms??

Comment: @GeraldBaretto: Huh, my bad. I've just read their Terms&Conditions plus FAQ, they really do allow you to send as many SMS as you want and do not exclude any automation. That's the first SMS service I've ever seen that allow this, all other services that I've worked with require you to pay or are free for private persons up to a certain limit.

Answer (score 0):

Then go through the `sms providing API` the web service that u are using .They must be providing any alternate for over come this issue.`Captcha` is used for preventing automated submissions on any site .

Answer (score 0):

Captcha code is generated at runtime, so it is not possible to predefine the captcha code in your application,thats the reason captcha is comes into the picture to prevent automation submissions on any site.